# Is C# 4.0 Tuple covariant

Tags: c#, covariance, tuples

(I would check this out for myself, but I don't have VS2010 (yet))

Say I have 2 base interfaces:

```
IBaseModelInterface
IBaseViewInterface
```

And 2 interfaces realizing those:

```
ISubModelInterface : IBaseModelInterface
ISubViewInterface : IBaseViewInterface
```

If I define a `Tuple<IBaseModelInterface, IBaseViewInterface>` I would like to set that based on the result of a factory that returns `Tuple<ISubModelInterface, ISubViewInterface>`.

In C# 3 I can't do this even though the sub interfaces realize the base interfaces. And I'm pretty sure C# 4 lets me do this if I was using `IEnumerable<IBaseModelInterface>` because it's now defined with the `in` keyword to allow covariance. So does `Tuple` allow me to do this?

From what (little) I understand, covariance is only allowed on interfaces, so does that mean there needs to be an `ITuple<T1, T2>` interface? Does this exist?

Comment: Note that the "in" keyword allows *contravariance*, not *covariance*. IEnumerable<T> is marked as *out* because *a T comes out of an IEnumerable<T>*.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`Tuple` is a class (well, a family of classes) - it's invariant by definition. As you mention later on, only interfaces and delegate types support generic variance in .NET 4.

There's no `ITuple` interface that I'm aware of. There could be one which would be covariant, as the tuples are immutable so you only get values "out" of the API.

Comment: I guess I could define my own IMyTuple<in TBaseModel, in TBaseView> that'd be neat

Comment: @RichK - if you do intend to write your own tuple class, you should carefully examine the comparison and equality semantics offered by BCL tuples. I assume you would want to preserve the same behavior as offered in the built in classes - and some of that behavior is non-obvious.

Comment: @Jon Skeet, there is a nongeneric `ITuple` interface, but it's internal

Comment: @smartcaveman: Yes, there is, `TRest` will be checked if it is `ITuple`.

Answer (score 9):

You can inherit from tuple for create your own Covariant Tuple. This way you avoid to have to rewrite your own equalities logic.

```
public interface ICovariantTuple<out T1>
{
    T1 Item1 { get; }
}
public class CovariantTuple<T1> : Tuple<T1>, ICovariantTuple<T1>
{
    public CovariantTuple(T1 item1) : base(item1) { }
}

public interface ICovariantTuple<out T1, out T2>
{
    T1 Item1 { get; }
    T2 Item2 { get; }
}
public class CovariantTuple<T1, T2> : Tuple<T1, T2>, ICovariantTuple<T1, T2>
{
    public CovariantTuple(T1 item1, T2 item2) : base(item1, item2) { }
}

etc.... for 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 items
```

Compile Fail

```
Tuple<Exception> item = new Tuple<ArgumentNullException>(null);
```

Compile Success

```
ICovariantTuple<Exception> item = new CovariantTuple<ArgumentNullException>(null);
```

[There is no base Tuple after 8 items](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.tuple), but it should be enough.

Comment: I like your solution with the interface and companion class! But what's the purpose of the empty factory? I think the last two examples show exactly what works and not.