# Is there Dictionary<Key,Value> without unique key?

Tags: c#, .net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Duplicate keys in .NET dictionaries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/146204/duplicate-keys-in-net-dictionaries)

I need to create a `Collection<string,object>`, one is a string and another one is an object.
I cannot use Dictionary since none of items is unique.

Is there any way to create `List<T,T>` ? Since i don't want to create an object to hold both values just to use it in single foreach loop.

Thanks

Comment: would an enum suit your needs? im not sure want you want to achieve.

Comment: why can't you create the `Dictionary<string, List<object>>`?

Comment: List of KeyValuePair? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5tbh8a42.aspx

Comment: Sorry, somehow code i placed was wiped

Comment: Use List<Tuple<string, object>>

Comment: @devsundar, i don't need inner List.

Comment: List of KeyValuePair<T,T> or List of Tuple<T,T> will work for you.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Try `List<Tuple<string, object>>`. Then you can get the usual linq support over the list to get at each `Tuple<string, object>`.

The [`Tuple<,>` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd268536) is available as of .NET 4 onwards, but you can easily mimick a tuple type of your own without too much hassle.

I think that tuples are considered equal based on their item values, but with `object` this would likely be reference equals and thus shouldn't likely be equal... if that made any sense!

More info on equality here:

[Surprising Tuple (in)equality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5069702/surprising-tuple-inequality)

**Update:**

If you need to associate a list of items with a key for the purposes of a lookup, the duplicate question answer correctly highlights the [`Lookup`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb460184.aspx) class (in your case, `Lookup<string, object>`), which would express your intent a little clearer than a `List<Tuple<string, object>>`.

Comment: A caveat is that Tuple is not available in older versions of .Net - it was introduced in .Net 4

Comment: @dash True, but a Tuple can be implemented generically for older versions, many people had Tuple before it was baked in. Either way the question is tagged version agnostically, so I reserve the right to assume the latest :-) thanks for the clarification though.

Comment: The comment is for other people who see your answer - PowerCollections has had it for ever :-)

Comment: @dash Indeed, in fact I spent a day here at the office removing our own Tuple from the code-base in favour of the .NET one as of v4.

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth, Tuple works better for me. I don't need to check equality, just to loop over Collection

Comment: The Lookup class cannot be instantuated?

Answer (score 12):

you can use

```
List<KeyValuePair<string,object>>
```

or

```
Dictionary<string,List<object>>
```

Comment: The `Dictionary<string,List<object>>` seems perfect for tracking a relationship with one-to-many cardinality.

Answer (score 4):

Try to create your custom class and use it

```
    class KeyValue<Tkey,TValue>
    {
       public Tkey Key {get;set;}
       public TValue Value {get;set;}
    }
```

use like

```
List<KeyValue<string,string>> list = new List<KeyValue<string,string>>();
```

Comment: Thanks, i wrote i that i want to avoid creating new object type.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe you could create a List of tuples using the [Tuple](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.tuple.aspx) class? Something like so:

```
List<Tuple<String, Object>> list = new List<Tuple<String, Object>>();
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're using .NET 4, you can use the Tuple ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.tuple.aspx ) object:

```
var list = new List<Tuple<string, object>>();
```

if you're using an earlier version of .NET, you can implement the Tuple class yourself: [Equivalent of Tuple (.NET 4) for .NET Framework 3.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7120845/equivalent-of-tuple-net-4-for-net-framework-3-5)

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using "Group by" then turned the grouped result into dictionary?

Comment: Not sure it will work in this case.