# Cannot Convert Dictionary to IDictionary in a Method Call

Tags: c#, .net, type-conversion, covariance, implicit-conversion

I can't for the life of me figure this out. Say I have the following two dictionary objects:

```
// Assume "query" is a LINQ queryable.
Dictionary<string, int> d1 = query.ToDictionary(k => k.Key, v => v.Value);
Dictionary<string, int>  d1 = query.ToDictionary(k => k.Key, v => v.Value);
```

The following statement produces a compile time error that an implicit conversion between a Dictionary and IDictionary is not possible:

```
// Compile time error!
Tuple<IDictionary<string, int>, IDictionary<string, int>> = Tuple.Create(d1, d2);
```

I have to do the conversion explicitly:

```
Tuple<IDictionary<string, int>, IDictionary<string, int>> = Tuple.Create(d1 as IDictionary<string, int>, d2 as IDictionary<string, int>);
```

I am not understanding why the compiler can't figure out the covariance operation - Dictionary implements IDictionary - especially since something like this will of course work as we all know:

```
IDictionary<string, int> d3 = d1;
```

I am sure there is a good reason for this behavior and I am curious what it is.

**Update 1:**
Just to clarify, I am curious about the behavior not how to solve the problem. I am aware of the different solutions :)

**Update 2:**
Thank you all for the great answers. I did not know `Tuple` was invariant and now I do.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Basically, the problem is that the `Tuple` family isn't covariant in its type arguments. It can't be, because it's a class. An interface or delegate version *could* be created that would be covariant, however, as there are no members accepting the type parameters in input positions.

This is simplest to see with [`Tuple<T1>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd386941.aspx):

```
Tuple<string> stringTuple = Tuple.Create("Foo");
Tuple<object> objectTuple = stringTuple;
```

This call:

```
Tuple.Create(d1, d2);
```

... is inferring both type arguments as `Dictionary<string, int>`, so you're trying to convert from `Tuple<Dictionary<string, int>, Dictionary<string, int>>` to 
`Tuple<IDictionary<string, int>, IDictionary<string, int>>`, which doesn't work.

The version with `as` changes the argument types so that type inference gives the desired type arguments - but it would be simpler to just write the type arguments directly, and avoid inference entirely, as per Sebastian's answer:

```
Tuple.Create<IDictionary<string, int>, IDictionary<string, int>>(d1, d2)
```

If you use `var` at this point, it's not *so* bad:

```
var x = Tuple.Create<IDictionary<string, int>, IDictionary<string, int>>(d1, d2);
```

The type of `x` will now be `Tuple<IDictionary<string, int>, IDictionary<string, int>>` which is what you want.

EDIT: As noted in comments, you might as well just use the constructor at that point:

```
var x = new Tuple<IDictionary<string, int>, IDictionary<string, int>>(d1, d2);
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. All the answers were great, but I am marking this one as the answer because of the details given.

Comment: @agarhy Of course, when (like here) you need to explicitly specify the type arguments `T1` and `T2` to the static `Tuple.Create<T1, T2>` method, you might as well just use the ordinary instance constructor of the generic type `Tuple<T1, T2>` with a new-object expression: `new Tuple<Something, SomethingElse>(d1, d2)`

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to assign...

```
Tuple<Dictionary<string, int>, Dictionary<string, int>>
```

...to...

```
Tuple<IDictionary<string, int>, IDictionary<string, int>>
```

...but the `Tuple<T1, T2>` is a class and therefore **[invariant](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2872938/533120)**.

Answer (score 2):

The type parameters for Tuple.Create are inferred from the types and thus the right hand side is a Tuple of two Dictionaries and this is a different type than Tuple of IDictionarys - if you explicitly add the type parameters to Tuple.Create to be of type IDictionary everything should work as expected because it is OK for the method parameters to be of a more specific type.

```
 Tuple.Create<IDictionary<string, int>,IDictionary<string, int>>(d1,d2)
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no conversion between a `Tuple<Dictionary<string, int>, Dictionary<string, int>>` and a `Tuple<IDictionary<string, int>, IDictionary<string, int>>` since classes in C# (and therefore the `Tuple<T1, T2>` class) do not support covariance.

The compiler has inferred the most specific type of the return type for your call to `Tuple.Create`, and does not use the type on the left-hand side during inferrence.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the variable type from `Dictionary<string, int>` to `IDictionary<string, int>.`

```
IDictionary<string, int> d1 = query.ToDictionary(k => k.Key, v => v.Value);
IDictionary<string, int>  d1 = query.ToDictionary(k => k.Key, v => v.Value);
```

Comment: That would work. But I am curious about the behavior, because if I use an implicit typed variable declaration, such as this, `var d1 = query.ToDictionary(k => k.Key, v => v.Value);` it won't work. I guess the question is, why do I have to do the conversion manually?

Comment: By using var, the compiler will set the type as Dictionary because Enumerable.ToDictionary returns Dictionary and not IDictionary.

Comment: You're right. I mis-typed what I meant. I meant to ask why passing `query.ToDictionary(k => k.Key, v => v.Value)` won't work. Thanks for your answer.